# Variable scope in modules

Tags: python, variables, module

Long story short: Why does this program output "0" instead of "5" and how can I make it output "5":
main.py:

```
from mod import *
setvar(5)
printvar()
```

mod.py:

```
var = 0
def setvar(x):
    var = x
def printvar():
    print("var =", var)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code in the `setvar` method merely creates a new local variable called `var` is assigned to the value of `x`.

You're modifying a global variable, you need to declare it as such.

```
var = 0
def setvar(x):
    global var
    var = x
def printvar():
    print("var =", var)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This actually works. Even after 2 years of programming, the way python handles variables seems still weird to me.